# how to use custom class names in WebDriverIO

Tags: css-selectors, webdriver-io, custom-selectors, webdriver-io-v4

how to find an element with custom class name in WebdriverIO

how to find element with this particular class name ng-repeat="document in documentsUploaded"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is: use CSS or xpath selectors https://webdriver.io/docs/selectors.html

ng-repeat is not a class, it's an element's attribute.

See also https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp and https://devhints.io/xpath

Answer (score 0):

The answer for your question is following CSS selector:

```
tr[ng-repeat='document in documentsUploaded']
```